# Is it safe to use a logical OR in a capture group to define it as optional?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

If I want to match explicitly using a PCRE library:

```
A green tunic
```

OR

```
A tunic
```

The full form is to use:

`^A (?:green )?tunic$`

Are there any caveats to using a logical OR or are these two forms equivalent?

`^A (?:green |)tunic$`

Note that I only care about detecting a match with regards to this question and preserving the order of capture groups are not important to me.

Comment: The number of capturing groups changes between the two forms. The second is also arguably less clear (fspov) and may not work in all regex implementations - some "require" that alternations contain sub-patterns. Unless capturing is needed, I'd have written it as: `^(?:This)?That$`

Comment: Your question is "primarily opinion-based" now. If you specify the regex library you are using, there may be an answer: optional capturing groups differ sometimes in what they return upon a match from a capturing group with an empty alternative.

Comment: You are correct to point this out and it is true but not something that I am worried about for my use case. I've clarified my question that I do not care about capture groups.

Comment: If you do not use capturing groups, the question is just opinion-based.

Comment: I've added additional clarification that this is for PCRE matching. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: The question is asking if there is some possible matching scenarios where the shorthand I use may fail to match in an identical way given something to the left or right or other placement of the group I want to be optional.

Comment: @user2864740 What do you mean by `fspov` and what makes it unclear to you? I read it as: "match this OR none". How does it read to you?

Comment: @Zhro For Some Point of View :) Since it alternates forms (hah!) the alternation slightly throws down my pattern-recognition/parsing of the construct. Hence why I would argue that it is "less clear". Of course Barmer points out non-equivalent cases so.. :}

Comment: No, there is no problem, `(?:foo|)` = `(?:foo)?`. Just make sure that empty alternative is at the end of the group. Whichever you use is a matter of preference/style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They will usually be equivalent, but there are some possible cases where they aren't.

When using `|`, some regexp engines are "eager", they use the leftmost match in the list of alternatives that succeeds. As a result, the order of alternatives can matter: `(This|)` is not always the same as `(|This)`. [regular-expression.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) gives some concrete examples of this.

When using `?`, the regexp engine is "greedy", it tries to find the longest match that succeeds (you can make it non-greedy by using `??`, then it prefers the shortest match).

In fact, these two features can be used together. The page linked above gives the example:

```
Get|GetValue|Set|SetValue
```

If the input string is

```
GetValue
```

an eager engine will just match `Get` rather than `GetValue`. But you can combine the alternatives with an optional group to make it always find the longest match.

```
Get(Value)?|Set(Value)?
```

However, I don't think your specific examples can encounter these problems. The fixed matches that surround the alternatives anchor it so that there's no ambiguity.

Comment: You are correct but I think I skirt around this issue in the case where it's a single logical comparison and my capture group ends with a space. Therefore it can't greedily match other words. Can you confirm?

Comment: Yes, if there's matches around this that constrain it, the ambiguities described cannot occur. I was trying to be more general in my answer.

Comment: Can you provide an example of an ambiguous match given my provided regex?

Comment: I don't think there is one because of the constraints.

Comment: I'm sorry, I read your response as "the ambiguities described **can** occur". Please forgive the confusion. Your answer is excellent in that it's not only thorough but also explains greedy versus non-greedy matching and provides an edge case in the absence of the constraint present my particular use case.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it clearer that your case doesn't run into problems.